# Multicollinearity: does if matter which variable I remove?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, multicollinearity

Say I'm running a multiple linear regression. I have 4 explanatory variables: A, B, C and D.

Pearsons correlation coefficient for A and B is 0.90. I decide to remove either A or B prior to running the multiple linear regression.

Will A and B both have exactly the same correlation coefficient with C and D, in which it doesn't matter which one of A or B I remove?

Or could A and B both have different correlation coefficients with C and D, in which I should remove the least correlated explanatory variable, A or B, prior to running the multiple linear regression?

Answer (score 2):

1. > Q : Will A and B both have exactly the same correlation coefficient with C
   >   and D, in which it doesn't matter which one of A or B I remove?

   A and B don't necessarily have the same correlation coefficient with C and D. Think of $X=[A,B,C]\sim N_3(0,\Sigma)$ where $\Sigma= \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0.9 & 0.1 \\
   0.9 & 1 & 0.3 \\
   0.1 & 0.3 & 1 
   \end{array} \right)$.

   For sample version, check it through experiment.

   ```
   library(mvtnorm)
   set.seed(123)
   Sigma <- c(1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.9, 1, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 1)
   Sigma <- matrix(Sigma, nrow = 3)
   X <- rmvnorm(n = 100, mean = rep(0,3), sigma = Sigma)
   cor(X)
   ```
2. > Q : could A and B both have different correlation coefficients with C and
   >   D, in which I should remove the least correlated explanatory variable,
   >   A or B

   This is not a good question. Suppose cor(A,C)=0.40, cor(A,D)=0.67, cor(B,C)=0.56, and cor(B,D)=0.27. B is more correlated to C than A, but A is more correlated to D than B. How do you define "the least correlated explanatory variable"? Should it be A or B? This situation is possible. Please try the following R code.

   ```
   set.seed(123)
   data <- matrix(rnorm(40), nrow=10)
   data[,3] <- -data[,3]
   colnames(data) <- c("A","B","C","D")
   cor(data)
   ```
3. If removing one variable between A and B is the only option, then the solutions I can think of are

   - drop the variable which is less correlated with the response
   - drop the variable which has larger Variance Inflation Factor (VIF)
   - fit 2 new models : one removing A and one removing B, and to see which new model suffers less multicollinearity. To measure multicollinearity, you can look at the VIF of each present variable or the Condition Number of $X'X$ where $X$ is the present design matrix
   - use variable selection method like stepwise regression and lasso regression to (hopefully) remove one variable

   I am not sure which are valid solutions or which is the best one, so any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Your response to Q1. doesn't work, because A and B are not correlated with each other

Comment: @luciano The answer is updated. You don't specify the type of the correlation coefficient : is it a population version or sample version? Sample correlation coefficient can be non-zero even if the population correlation coefficient is 0. When talking about multicollinearity in regression, we usually mean the sample correlation coefficient, because the population version is unknown. It is possible that population version is high but sample version is low. In this case, you can not even detect multicollinearity, as all methods are with respect to the sample.